# QUESTION ABOUT PATENT US1743543

Tags: us1743543

https://www.google.com/patents/US1743543
IS THIS PATENT EXPIRED OR STILL VALID AS I PLAN TO DO SOMETHING THAT MAY BE A BIT SIMILAR

Comment: Please don’t write in all caps. It’s the internet version of yelling.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check patent expiry or current legal status 
 of latest patents then you can do so by going to http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/index.html and clicking on public PAIR

Answer (score 0):

Patents of that era expired 17 years from the grant date. Since 1995, patents expire 20 years from the filing (or priority) date. So US1743543 expired in 1947. Although Google Patents can't necessarily be relied upon, you can see that the status is listed as "Expired - Lifetime". You can freely practice what is claimed in this patent. You should be aware that there could be other patents that are relevant. One good idea is to look at patents that [cite this one](https://patents.google.com/patent/US1743543#citedBy) for other relevant IP. Since the patent is so old you may need to repeat this procedure on any patent that looks similar.

Comment: @FaizaKhalifa if one of the answers suits you, it would be great for you to accept it by clicking in the check mark.